# How to connect flutter to localhost mysql database

Tags: mysql, dart, flutter

I want to connect a localhost mysql db to flutter but I'm failing to do so. I tried mysql1 with these connections:

```
ConnectionSettings(
        host: '10.0.2.2',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: "root",
        db: 'company'
```

and i tried replacing host by 'localhost' and it didn't work. Any help? I am not using an emulator.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'it didn't work'?  Do you have any error message?

Comment: Yes sorry, here's the error: Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 51782

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A connection directly to MySQL (or any other database access directly from clients)  is not a good idea, except Firebase. 
If you want to interact with the MySql db a better solution is to create a server app and expose some HTTP REST API (with node.js, php ect.). With the API you can provide also a token for the client in order to access your data.
You can make HTTP requests https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html.

Now if for any reason you want still to connect directly to MySQL just keep in mind that any client application can access your DB with **write** permission in this case (and this is not a good practice at all!) just for a test example you can try creating a php file:

// Connect and insert data example

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST["value"])) {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $user = "username";
        $pw = "password";
        $db = "data";
        #Connect to Server
        $con = new Mysqli($servername, $user, $pw, $db) or die(Mysqli_errno());

        $value =htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($_POST["value"])));

        $sql = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tableName (value) VALUES ('$value')");
        $result = $sql->execute();
        if ($result) {
            echo "Success";
        }
        else {
            echo "Failed";
        }
        $con->close();
    } 
    else {
       echo "Not found";
    } 
?>
```

Also need to write the flutter part that make the request on http.post

```
void post() async {
    var result = await http.post(
        "http://{your url}/index.php",
         body: {
           "value": "Test DB Connection"
         }
    );
    print(result.body);
}
```

Comment: please can you help me to know my URL ?.....and where can I find some php template code ?

Comment: Take a look on this one https://medium.com/@santosenoque.ss/how-to-connect-flutter-app-to-mysql-web-server-and-phpmyadmin-e100f47bfb82

Comment: Hii, @nike , can I use java instead of php for doing the same operation?

Comment: @Bhupesh_decoder yes you can use any language that runs within your server

Comment: @nike Why connecting to databases except for Firebase is not a good idea? Can you help in explaining that?

Comment: @HusseinAl-Mosawi connecting directly to a database you won't be able to protect your data store once any client application has write access. 
How you approach API security will depend on what kind of data is being transferred. 

The best way may be to host a server that provides access to a database (e.g: it can be used Express - Node.js ) while exposing an API to Flutter to make requests.

https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/security/api-security#:~:text=Why%20is%20API%20security%20important,personal%20data%20for%20public%20consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting directly to your database through a client(third party application) isn't very advisable.

It poses a lot of security risks...
Instead use http package or dio package from pub.dev

Create an api (a page that echoes json_encode($data)) from your server with any backend language then you can pick up that information using http.post in your flutter application.

This link helped me, you can try it out:
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data#4-get-a-title-from-user-input