# i got an error in http :socketException : OS error : connection refused

Tags: flutter

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
>   SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address =
>   127.0.0.1, port = 36832

Comment: What OS are you using? Did you try checking to see if port  36832 is open?

Comment: To be honest we need more information, other than just the traceback. For example is your code in python or are you using something else to work with Dart? What OS are you using: Linux, Macos, Windows? Networking commands in terminal differ across all three OS Platforms. I assume this is on your local machine given the IP address, but what it is  local just means you have something exposed to that port via your code. Furthermore, this port could already be in use or just plain simple "Not Open." However to determine that, we would need to know what OS you are using, what the code is doing.

Comment: i' m  using  Windows 10

Comment: i m trying to connect flutter with MySQL db

Comment: Do the following with elevated powershell by running it run as admin `Test-NetConnection -Port 36832 -InformationLevel "Detailed"`

Comment: Make sure you post that output as well within your question as it will help other viewers better understand what is going on in your system.

Comment: Also see if this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118535/how-to-connect-flutter-to-localhost-mysql-database

Comment: You will probably see something similar to `WARNING: TCP connect to (2a01:XXX:XXXX::XX: 36832) failed` just the IP Address will probably be different for you.

Comment: If it is indeed closed check out this article on how to open ports on Windows 10: https://winaero.com/blog/open-port-windows-firewall-windows-10/

Comment: thanks for your attention an this is the output :

Comment: RemoteAddress           : 13.107.4.52
RemotePort              : 36832
NameResolutionResults   : 13.107.4.52
MatchingIPsecRules      :
NetworkIsolationContext : Internet …...

Comment: Did you see anything in terms of TCP failure, I don't see much from the output you gave.

Comment: AVERTISSEMENT : TCP connect to (13.107.4.52 : 36832) failed                                                                                                                                                                                     
ComputerName            : internetbeacon.msedge.net
RemoteAddress           : 13.107.4.52
RemotePort              : 36832

Comment: Yeah make sure that your port is open on your local for outbound and then open the port on the destination for inbound. Is all of this running on the same machine, or is the Remote Address running elsewhere? If so is your MySQL DB running on an external network or is it on your internal network? Are you able to connect into the external network VPN?

Comment: but how can i check if my port is open or no ?

Comment: i tried to add port 80 but Nothing is changed

Comment: because apache and MySQL are working fine

Comment: If you went to check //localhost:80 or you tried to curl it you should receive something. Also I posted links with the answer on how to check if the port is open in Powershell. Furthermore, there just really is not a lot of information here. I have no clue what your code is doing unless you provide it, neither does the community for that matter. Also, we don't know if your LAMP server is running locally or not. I would assume that you are trying to connect to a remote database, but that is an assumption. If you really want a good answer that fixes your issue, please edit your question.

Comment: By the way I assume a LAMP because you mentioned Apache. The fact of the matter is we need more information on what you are using to connect to the database. What lines of code of commands are you using? I know I can use Dart, I assume Python, but I honestly I have no idea what you are using...all I know is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The TCP/IP connection to the host , port  has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."

Test this by running the following command on a Windows Machine:

```bsh
Test-NetConnection -Port 36832 -InformationLevel "Detailed"
```

You will get details similar to:

```bsh
WARNING: TCP connect to (2a01:XXX:XXXX::XX: 36832) failed
```

THIS INDICATES THE PORT IS NOT OPEN

If you get something like:

```bsh
AVERTISSEMENT : TCP connect to (13.107.4.52 : 36832) failed ComputerName : internetbeacon.msedge.net RemoteAddress : 13.107.4.52 RemotePort : 36832
```

THIS INDICATES A DNS ISSUE.

How to open ports in Windows 10 via Elevated Powershell Prompt:
https://winaero.com/blog/open-port-windows-firewall-windows-10/

How to resolve DNS issues in Windows 10 on Local and Remotes Hosts:
https://www.ghacks.net/2016/10/20/how-to-fix-resolving-host-issues-on-windows/

You can also verify DNS Issues with `nslookup` it runs on Linux, Mac, and Windows. You will have to most likely install the modules with Chocolatey, Brew, Yum, df, aptly, and other package managers that are used by the variety of flavors for Linux. Furthermore, you can look at the following for more information

http://techgenix.com/10-ways-troubleshoot-dns-resolution-issues/
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-troubleshoot-client-dns/

Other things you can try:

```bsh
traceroute
tcpdump
nmap
```

Please check that the Firewall Rules are correct on both local and remote machines, furthermore ensure that you have the ability to connect via ipsec/firewall rules and that your Database is configured to accept incoming connection on that port.

```
netstat -tlnp
```